# Pandas Update on DataFrame to carryover NaN from second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

When updating one DataFrame based on info from second one the NaN's are not transferred.
With below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[4,5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[7,np.nan,6]})
df1.update(df2)
```

The new DataFrame will look as below:

[image]

So the value from df2 is not transferred as this is a NaN

[image]

Normally this is probably an expected outcome but not in the particular case that I'm working on.
For the moment how I deal with it is that I replace all NaNs with a value or string that signalizes to me that it's something I need to check but I was wondering if there is an actual solution to pass the NaN as an update?

[image]

Comment: I think `update` docs - `Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.` - so need only replace like `-999` like mntioned in question. `df1.update(df2.fillna(-999))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is a bit more involved, but solves the problem as well without using `fillna` or so:

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', suffixes=('___',''), on=['A'], indicator=True)
df3['finalB'] = df3.apply(lambda x: x['B'] if x['_merge'] == 'both' else x['B___'], axis=1)
df3[['A','finalB']]
```

Output:

```
     A  finalB
0  1.0     7.0
1  2.0     NaN
2  3.0     6.0
3  4.0     7.0
4  5.0     8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like this solution as it also gives some flexibility for application in another tasks. Once again thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Concat dataframes then remove duplicated index:

```
>>> pd.concat([df2, df1]).loc[lambda x: ~x.index.duplicated()].sort_index()
   A    B
0  1  7.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  6.0
3  4  7.0
4  5  8.0
```

Comment: I think this gets rid of the NaNs, but does not in the end give rise to the effect of `signalizes to me that it's something I need to check`

Comment: Thanks to point me out, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good approach as well. Thank you!